# awk format to print lines with specific columns

Tags: string, awk, format

I want to print only the lines that have specific string say "fgfgfg" in column
3 *or* column 4 *and* column 2 start with fg
I'm using the following command but it also prints lines which doesn't have fg as the starting characters in column 2?

```
 awk '{if (($3 == "fgfgfg" || $4 == "fgfgfg") && $2 ~ /fg/) print $0}' file_name
```

the must condition is that column $2 must start with 'fg' and I also want to add a condition that column 2 start with fg and followed by 5 digits? 
any help please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 awk '(($3 == "fgfgfg") || ($4 == "fgfgfg")) && ($2 ~ /^fg[0-9]{5}/)' file_name
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that column 2 starts with `fg` you need to use:

```
$2 ~ /^fg/
```

note the `^`. It is the *start of the line* anchor. If you omit it the regex would match `fg` at any position within the string.

Btw, you can simplify the command:

```
awk '(($3 == "fgfgfg") || ($4 == "fgfgfg")) && $2 ~ /^fg/' file
```

Comment: In this simple case, you can also use `substr($2, 1, 2) == "fg"` if you'd rather not use regular expressions.

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks for your answer, but I need to say column 3 or column 4 should contain the string "fgfgfg". and then column 2 must start with 'fg'
followed by 5 digits in any case (whether column 3 or column 4 contain the string)

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Changed the answer